Is 1 John 5:7 a false verse?
1 John 5:7 (DRA)  And there are three who give testimony in heaven, the Father, the Word, and the Holy Ghost. And these three are one.

Could you please explain on what basis you think the verse is false?

Yes.
The NIV Study Bible, which is well known for its ardent belief in the Trinity, says, “The addition is not found in any Greek manuscript or NT translation prior to the sixteenth century.”
While it does not contradict other NT passages directly, it is not part of the inspired text. The Father, the word and the spirit all bear witness to the work of God within creation. Whether they 'give testimony' is another matter.

NKJV that bear witness in heaven: the Father, the Word, and the Holy Spirit.

It is difficult to imagine how the word bears witness. It is not a person according to 1 John 1:1-2 but a 'which' and an 'it' through which God creates. So the underlying inference is rather moot unless a trinitarian (or binitarian) view is held.
We note there is no mention of 'son' so it is not explicitly trinitarian as the creeds speak of the son as the second entity of the godhead, not the word.
It is NOT original, it IS an addition so a true Bible student should not regard it as having any value.

You made this statement, "It is difficult to imagine how the word bears witness. It is not a person according to 1 John 1:1-2 but a 'which' and an 'it' through which God creates." Reconcile your statement with 1 John 1:1-2, "What was from the beginning, what we have heard, what we have seen with our eyes, what we beheld and our hands handled concerning the Word if Life--vs2, and the life was manifested and we have seen and bear witness and proclaim to you the eternal life which was with the Father and manifested to us." How did the disciples manage to see and handle an it/non-person?

@Mr.Bond Many Trinitarians do not accept the Johannine comma. Nor do I. To speak of 'Father' and 'Word' is unscriptural. 'Father and Son' is elsewhere found. The history, involving Erasmus, is telling. The only manuscript he could find was Latin, not Greek. 'Word' is an aspect of the second person of the Deity. But it is not the whole Person and I think you are stating that and I agree.

@Mr.Bond are you beginning to see more clearly than before? I'm intrigued by your Q. How did the disciples manage to see and handle an it/non-person? They begin referring to the word - the 'it', which MANIFESTED as a person in Jesus. NOW they can touch this previously untouchable word. It's quite simply when you read without all the baggage of dogma and misdirection. The Bible does not contradict itself - when one removes the errors introduced by our biased publishers.
